# Cannot figure out why SSH server is slower in sending the version string when using a faster connection

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

Does anyone has an idea of what might cause SSH being slow in sending the version string?

I have the same client and the same server machine.

When the client is connected through network 1, the ping time to the server is around 6ms, however, `time ssh server exit` takes around 5 seconds.
When the client is connected through network 2, the ping time to the server is around 60ms, but  `time ssh server exit` takes less than 1 seconds.

When connected to Network 1, the client is just one router away from the server (at least that is what traceroute shows). When connected to Network 2. the client is about 20 routers away (traceroute shows that it will go through that router finally).

When connected to Network 1, `ssh -vvv server` shows that the delay is actually between

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/hongce/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/hongce/.ssh/config line 61: Applying options for xxx
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "XXXX.XXXX.XXXX" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to XXXX.XXXX.XXXX [XXX.XXX.XX.XX] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/hongce/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/hongce/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/hongce/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/hongce/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/hongce/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/hongce/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/hongce/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/hongce/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
```

and

```
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.10
```

where you can see it is after the connection has been established.
(I replaced the server domain name and ip address in the above message with XXXX)

On the server side, setting `UseDNS` to `no` does not significantly lower the ssh delay, (but I think it is in effect, because the later logins will no longer show the domain name but just the ip of the previous login source).

So my question is, what may be the cause of the delay for sending the version string when connecting through a faster network?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found an answer to it.

I finally strace into sshd and by looking at the system call trace, I found that at the time of the client waiting for the version string, the forked sshd child process is waiting on `read`, while 6 is related to `avahi-daemon` as shown by the trace.

```
...
[pid  5651] close(6)                    = 0
[pid  5651] mprotect(0x7f1e081b4000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
[pid  5651] munmap(0x7f1e0b773000, 146949) = 0
[pid  5651] socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_STREAM, 0) = 6
[pid  5651] fcntl(6, F_GETFD)           = 0
[pid  5651] fcntl(6, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
[pid  5651] connect(6, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/avahi-daemon/socket"}, 110) = 0
[pid  5651] fcntl(6, F_GETFL)           = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
[pid  5651] fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFSOCK|0777, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid  5651] mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f1e0b7c3000
[pid  5651] lseek(6, 0, SEEK_CUR)       = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
[pid  5651] write(6, "RESOLVE-ADDRESS 10.6.62.19\n", 27) = 27
[pid  5651] read(6,
```

Googling results in the following message

> Avahi is a system which facilitates service discovery on a local network via the mDNS/DNS-SD protocol suite. This enables you to plug your laptop or computer into a network and instantly be able to view other people who you can chat with, find printers to print to or find files being shared.

Since I don't need it at all, I just turn it off.

`sudo service avahi-daemon stop`

Problem solved.

Comment: Is your target hostname of the form `something.local` by any chance? The `.local` suffix was dedicated to mDNS use and might get mDNS lookup delays on modern systems. However, this only includes two-part domain names: if the name has three or more components like `some.thing.local`, it should be still usable without extra delays.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure if I get what you mean by hostname. What `/bin/hostname`  returns has no dots in it.